# Problem adding ppa:ubuntugis-unstable

Tags: installation, ubuntu, linux

I'm trying to add the ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable repository to my ubuntu.
I type:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable
```

And I'm getting:

```
Cannot add PPA: 'ppa/ubuntugis/ubuntugis-unstable'. 
Please check that the PPA name or format is correct.
```

I can ping ppa.lauchpad.net and apt is working (just did an upgrade). Can anyone spot what is wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Found out that I need to set the proxy in my terminal prior to using add-apt-repository. I though it would honor the proxy settings from apt.

More details here:
https://askubuntu.com/questions/53146/how-do-i-get-add-apt-repository-to-work-through-a-proxy/102505#102505?s=a9a1fe070785469bb6cdf8ca633bcdb8